# Expected a list of dataframe got just one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Am trying to convert list of sheets from an excel file into a csv, so beginning with the following codes, i want to read the files first, but i only get the first sheet, and the rest are lost

```
import pandas as pd

def accept_xcl_file(file):
    xcl_file = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    sheets= xcl_file.sheet_names
    file = xcl_file.parse(sheet_names = sheets)
    return file,sheets

file, sheet  = accept_xcl_file('Companies.xlsx')

sheet >>
```

**this is the output from sheet
['companies',
 'fruits',
 'vehicles',
 'sales',
 'P&L',
 'price',
 'clubs',
 'countries',
 'housing',
 'life-expectancy']**

```
file['fruits'] >>
```

***i get a keyerror when i try to index the file, but when i use 'companies' key i get the correct data. going by the documentation i should expect a DataFrame or dict of DataFrames
anyhelp.***.

Answer (score 1):

The [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) method is already available in pandas to import Excel data.

Try this instead of your code:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_excel('Companies.xlsx')
# file is a dict object
# keys are the sheet names as strings
# items are the pd.DataFrame objects containing sheet data
```

Comment: it is a class work, and i am to use this function, i can of dont know why  it is behaving like this ??

Comment: Try listing out the keys that have been imported using `print(list(file.keys()))`. Maybe there's a typo in your sheet names.